# application Name for use with Azure KeyVault: Do I need an Azure Application to use Azure Keyvault?

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I am trying to run GetAppConfigSettings.ps1 from the example [in Microsoft Docs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45343)

The script asks me to supply values for

```
vaultName
resourceGroupName
applicationName
location
```

I am stuck on applicationName

I want my application to run locally in Visual Studio. 
I do want to use Azure KeyVault for encryption
What do I set up for the applicationName ?

I did start to add an Application to the Azure directory but it required a Redirect URI

The tooltip mentions that this is "The URI to which Microsoft Azure AD will redirect in response to an OAuth 2.0 request. The value does not need to be a physical endpoint, but must be a valid URI.

If I do need to set up an application so that I can have an application name to give to Key vault, what do I put in the Redirect URI given that I am writing a console application to run on my own pc.

I am choosing Native for the application type since the help for Application type mentions 
"Choose "Web app/API" to add an application that represents a web application, a web API, or both. Choose "Native" to add an application that can be installed on a user's device or computer.

So I guess Native = Edge and Web = Cloud

The script still fails maybe I need to do something about a self signed certificate.

It seems before I can use Key Vault I need to understand Azure Applications even though I am not writing one
And before I can understand Azure Applications I need to understand Self Signing Certificates

Comment: I am trying out an application created with the Redirect URI = http://localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in order to access KV your app will need to be registered in AD as an application, where you will define the shared ID and client secret. You need to go through that process.  App name is the name there.

Redirect URI is irrelevant, just add some valid URI like http://somedomain.com/appnane

Your app will need the client ID and secret to connect to KV. If I recall rightly you can do this easily based on sample code but it needs an AD nuget for the token and nuget for KV SDK